# php includeing file with in other file

Tags: php

Is it possible to include php files  in this format like:
B is included in A and
C is included in B

I am getting a in finite execution of B when I do this in this format.

Please help me.

Here is my code for index.php

```
<a href="index.php?page=js"> HOme</a><br/>
<a href="index.php?page=css"> css</a><br/>  
<a href="index.php?page=memu"> menu</a><br/>
<a href="index.php?page=php"> php</a><br/><?php

$p=$_GET['page'];
$page=$p.".php";
if(file_exists($page))
        include($page);
else
    echo "what are u looking foe";
?>
<div>
```

MY CODE FOR index1.php

```
<a href="index.php?page=js"> HOme</a><br/>
<a href="index.php?page=index"> css</a><br/>    
<a href="index.php?page=memu"> menu</a><br/>
<a href="index.php?page=php"> php</a><br/>

<div id="content">
    <?php

    $p=$_GET['page'];
    $page=$p.".php";
    if(file_exists($page))
            include($page);
    else
        echo "what are u looking foe";
    ?>
<div>
```

here index1.php is top menu for a page and index.php is the side menu in the page.. when we press the link "css" in index1.php the it opens side menu index1.php so when i press css in index.php i need to display the both top menu(index1.php) and the side menu( index.php) and the css content in the index.php link

Comment: `include_once()`

Comment: thank u its working

Comment: but iam not getting the content of the index1 when I click the link of css

Comment: @anveshtadii Which link of css? One of them goes to `css.php`, the other goes to `index.php`. Why should they load `index1`?

Comment: page css in index.php

Comment: here index1.php is top menu for a page and index.php is the side menu in the page.. when we press the link "css" in index1.php the it opens side menu index1.php so when i press css in index.php i need to display the both top menu(index1.php) and the side menu( index.php) and the css content in the index.php link

Answer (score 0):

The error your are describing happens when you open `index.php?page=index` or   `index1.php?page=index`.
`index.php` will try to load itself recursively in both cases.

Your router `index.php` should be different from all content files, for example like this:

```
./index.php
./content-files/index.php
./content-files/css.php
./content-files/menu.php
```

Then you change your code a little:

```
$p = $_GET['page'];
$p = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/', '', $p); // For security
$page = 'content-files/' . $p . ".php";
if (file_exists($page))
        include($page);
else
    echo "what are u looking foe";
```

I added a line to prevent things like `index.php?page=..%2Findex` which could be used to read files that are not supposed to be opened here.

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite recursion in your code. You say you want `index.php` to include the php defined by `$_GET['page']`, in this case `index1.php`. That `index1.php` does exactly the same as `index.php`, it includes the php defined by `$_GET['page']`, in this case `index1.php`. So `index1.php` includes itself over and over.

There is a problem with you code because 1. You include your menu twice. 2. You use the same variable to define the "page" while I think you mean two different things. 3. You do not test the page variable, which is coming from the user, this could cause you security problems and errors if you do not test if the file exists first.